# How to get the year-to-date number of new users from these two tables using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I am a new user of LINQ and I am trying to come up with a LINQ statement that will retrieve the number of new users with the default role. In details, I have the following two tables:

```
Users Table: UserID, Name
Roles Table: ID, RoleName, DateCreated, UserID
```

Since the User might have more than one role, I need to retrieve a year-to-date number of new users who have only one Role ID. If the user has more than one role, then he should not be counted.

I could be able to come up with the following query:

```
var newUsers= from user in context.Users
        where user.Roles.Where(role => role.UserID == user.UserID).Count() == 1
```

but when I added the following condition, I did not get the correct result:

```
where(role => role.DateCreated.Year == year && role.DateCreated.Month <= month)
```

**Could you please tell me how I can get the number of new users who have only one role id?**

Comment: What did you get from the above query then?

Comment: Do you know id of default role?

Comment: Is DateCreated a Nullable<DateTime> ?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov, I don't need to know the id of the default role. I am only concerned about the number of roles that the user has. If he has only one role which is the default role, then he is considered as a new user.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get this user with only one role:

```
var query = context.Users.Where(a => (a.Roles.DateCreated.HasValue ? (a.Roles.DateCreated.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && a.Roles.DateCreated.Value.Month <= DateTime.Now.Month) : false))
                   .GroupBy(c => new { c.Roles, c.UserID })
                   .Where(c => c.Count() == 1)
                   .Select(c => c.Key.UserID);
```

It may have syntax error but you get the idea!